# how to use google assistant start_conversation() API in python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

start_conversation() API according to documentation provided [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/library/python/) should manually start recording and sending it to google servers. But I don't see this happening. Using this API I don't get a response. Please provided an example has to how to use it.

Background:

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 as hardware platform and on which I have installed the google assistant SDK. So far, I'm successfully able to trigger the device using hotwords and also get response. I wanted to get rid of hotword triggering and start conversing just like that. For this purpose I have used set_mic_mute API which makes the assistant not to listen to the word. After this I'm calling the start_conversation API to start sending my query to google server. Nothing seems to work after this point. Please do provide some inputs to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/library/python/) of `start_conversation()`:
This method is a no-op if the Assistant is not started or has been muted.

If you want to control how you trigger the Assistant (e.g. by the press of a button), you should consider using the lower level [Assistant gRPC API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/grpc/).

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I'm planning to use Assistant gRPC API's in my future version of project.